Unsure about a logic question by Brilliant.org
For context: I wanted to try out brilliant.org for a while after seeing it on numerous sponsored videos by educational YouTubers. I decided to try its level 1 logic course and everything seems to make sense until this question came along. I am posting this because I feel that something is slightly off about this question and I am unsure if it's just me. Please correct me if there is nothing wrong about the question.
The question that intrigued me begins in the 2nd screenshot where the answer says that all 3 wore red hats. The first screenshot sets up the context of the question.
screenshot 1
screenshot 2
Solution proposed by brilliant.org: (First, let's find the minimum number of red hats. Suppose there was only one red hat, for example, on Alice's head.Then Alice wouldn't have said, "I see at least one red hat." She did say that, so she can't be the only one wearing a red hat. There must be at least two red hats.
Let's suppose that Marv is wearing a red hat, too. Now everyone sees at least one red hat, which makes it possible that all three of them exclaim in unison, “I see at least one red hat!”
Now, let's see if Alice (or Marv) can say “I don’t know what color hat I’m wearing” in the next phase. Note that Alice now realizes Marv saw blue on Blorb and red on herself before saying “I see at least one red hat.” So she does know she's wearing a red hat. (Similarly, Marv deduces his hat color, red, from Alice's statement.) So, assuming two red hats leads to a contradiction.
Since Alice and Marv didn't know their own hat colors, Blorb must also be wearing a red hat. There can't be any blue hats at all.)
My opinion: In the question, it states "After thinking for a moment, they all say at once, “I don’t know what color hat I’m wearing.” What confuses me is the author of this question could deduce the solution with the same information presented to alice, marv and blorb who couldn't deduce even after "thinking" and pondering with the SAME information accessible to them. Assuming everyone is logical and truthful, the final statement: " I don't know what color hat I'm wearing " points to the fact that they have considered all possible outcomes and are yet unable to arrive with all 3 wearing red. The proposed solution states that alice and marv are able to tell what hat they're wearing if the solution is 2 red and 1 blue which would not fit the question's constraint: "I don't know what color hat I'm wearing". That leaves us with only ONE possibility left which is all 3 are red hats. WHY ON EARTH are they still doubting themselves and saying "I don't know" if the only possibility is all 3 are red hats?? I believe this question is flawed. Please correct me if I'm wrong :/

I think you should ask this question on puzzling stack exchange

Let's break down your thought process

My opinion: In the question, it states "After thinking for a moment, they all say at once, “I don’t know what color hat I’m wearing.”

To be clear, there are 3 distinct phases

The very start when there is no public information.
After everyone has shared that they see a red hat.
After everyone has shared that they don't know the color of their hate.

You seem to think of this as just 1 combined mess, as opposed to recognizing that there is different PRIVATE information made PUBLIC available over time.

What confuses me is the author of this question could deduce the solution with the same information presented to alice, marv and blorb who couldn't deduce even after "thinking" and pondering with the SAME information accessible to them.

The following is true of the situation (You may not understand why it's true as yet. If so, pretend that I'm stating a theorem first.)
At phase 1 or 2, neither an outside observer, Alice, Marv, or Blorb cannot deduce the colors of the hats.
At phase 3, an outside observer, Alice, Marv, and Blorb all can deduce the color of the hats.

Assuming everyone is logical and truthful, the final statement: " I don't know what color hat I'm wearing " points to the fact that they have considered all possible outcomes and are yet unable to arrive with all 3 wearing red.

Right, at phase 2, everyone don't know what color hat they are wearing.
After they announce it, we are in phase 3, and THEN they know.

The proposed solution states that alice and marv are able to tell what hat they're wearing if the solution is 2 red and 1 blue which would not fit the question's constraint: "I don't know what color hat I'm wearing".

Let me try to explain this another way.
Suppose Alice+Marv had red hats, and Blorb has a blue hat.
Let's consider Alice's point of view.
At phase 1 (and 2 and 3), Alice sees Blorb's blue hat.
At phase 2, Alice now knows that Marv see at least 1 red hat (Marv shared that PRIVATE information, Alice didn't know that in phase 1).
If Alice was wearing a blue hat, then Marv sees 2 blue hat, so couldn't have seen at least 1 red hat.
Hence, Alice can conclude that she is wearing a red hat.
Can you likewise show that in this scenario, when we consider Marv's point of view, then Marv can conclude that he is wearing a red hat?
If you understood that, then you should review the relevant part of the proposed solution to see if which part was confusing.

 Let's suppose that Marv is wearing a red hat, too. Now everyone sees at least one red hat, which makes it possible that all three of them exclaim in unison, “I see at least one red hat!” Now, let's see if Alice (or Marv) can say “I don’t know what color hat I’m wearing” in the next phase. Note that Alice now realizes Marv saw blue on Blorb and red on herself before saying “I see at least one red hat.” So she does know she's wearing a red hat. (Similarly, Marv deduces his hat color, red, from Alice's statement.)


That leaves us with only ONE possibility left which is all 3 are red hats.

From the above, in phase 2, when Alice announced that she doesn't know her hat color (PRIVATE information that she made PUBLIC ),  she's essentially announcing that the other 2 hats she sees are red.
So in phase 3, Marv+Blorb know that they are wearing red hats.

WHY ON EARTH are they still doubting themselves and saying "I don't know" if the only possibility is all 3 are red hats??

To reiterate, in phase 1 and 2 they do not know what they are wearing.
Only by iteratively making PRIVATE information PUBLIC, in phase 3 do they know what they are wearing.

I believe this question is flawed. Please correct me if I'm wrong :/

I hope this helps clarifies your concerns.
The question is not flawed.
Bonus: And if you understood this, try to figure out what the outsider observer knows at each phase.
In particular, in phase 3, are they also able to finally deuce that all 3 hats are red, WITHOUT seeing anyone's hats?

If I understand correctly and to answer the first part of your bonus question,
at phase 1, the outside observer knows nothing as no information is shared.
at phase 2, the outsider narrows it down to two possibilities: 2 red hats, 1 blue hat or 3 red hats.
at phase 3, the outsider now knows its 3 red hats, as everyone does not know what hat they're wearing.
for the 2nd part of ur qn, could you further clarify what you mean?  Im not sure if you mean they cannot see anyone's hat from the very beginning or they could see only in phase 1 and 2 but not in 3. Thanks for the kind help btw : D

@SingaporeanHermit Correct. The "without seeing anyone's hats" means that the outside observer (aka you the problem solver) cannot see what Alice/Marv/Blorb is wearing at any phase, but can ultimately deduce that it is 3 red hats based on the information that is shared.

If I understand your doubt correctly, the issue is that we can deduce that all of them wear red hats only after they all said that they cannot deduce their colors. If they had the chance to say a third statement they would be able to correctly identify that all three of them wear red hats.
In other words, they say (2) "I don't know what color hat I'm wearing" only after knowing that all of them said (1) "I see at least one red hat". If the reader/the author were to make a statement only after knowing (1) they wouldn't be able to conclude that all of the hats are red.
It is (1)+(2) that implies that all hats are red, not (1) alone.
